# How to partition a given list of numbers to N array where the sum of each array is closest to a specific number, M?

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

Given array `int[] arr = {3,4,7,8,9,10,12,14,14,25,25,28,30,32}`

Given specific number `int M = 33`

The question is how do I partition the array `arr` to `N` amount of arrays so that each sum of the array is trying to reach 33 (since M=33). My main purpose is just to get a lower value of N and the final result looks something like this:

```
arr1 = {32}
arr2 = {3,30}
arr3 = {4,28}
arr4 = {8,25}
arr5 = {7,25}
arr6 = {4,14}
arr7 = {9,12,10}
```

This results me in N=7 arrays, correct me if you get lower than 7 arrays as I am trying to get as low amount of `N` as possible.

Constraint:

1. Only can use each element once in the array given

Comment: That's the knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I suggest using brute force to iterate through all elements of the array that sum up 32, then, each time arr[i] + arr[j] = 32 return it as a new object, return new int[] {}; (the method should be an array return type)